# Clear all instances of an interval

Tags: jquery, intervals

Is it possible to remove all instances of an interval?

Code Snippet:

```
function callInterval() {
    theInterval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Interval called");
    }, 1000);
}

callInterval();
setTimeout(callInterval, 4000);

setTimeout(clearThem, 8000);

function clearThem() {
    clearInterval(theInterval);
}
```

The Code snippet above just removes one interval, the other continues.

Comment: because you are overriding the `theInterval` with new value... so only the last one will be cleared

Comment: any suggestion to get both cleared? @ArunPJohny

Comment: It's recognized that you want to be able to clear, but what is the objective for this code other than log to console. Understanding use case will help

Comment: this code is just to demonstrate. For sure i do more stuff inside this interval, but i think it's useless to provide more informations what i'm doing inside. @charlietfl

Comment: you can use an array to store multiple references and clear all of them on `clear` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8oy2g5ef/1/

Comment: The point being will you have many intervals needed at same time, or are you looking to repeat something...big difference

Comment: thanks for this nice snippet @ArunPJohny. Works fine!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you are overriding the value of the variable `theInterval` every time you call `callInterval`, so it will hold only the last reference.

One easy solution here is to use an array to hold all the references and then remove them when calling clear

```js
var theInterval = [];

function callInterval(test) {
  theInterval.push(setInterval(function() {
    snippet.log("Interval called: " + test);
  }, 1000));
}

callInterval(1);
setTimeout(callInterval.bind(undefined, 2), 4000);

setTimeout(clearThem, 8000);

function clearThem() {
  theInterval.forEach(clearInterval);
  clearInterval.length = 0; //hack to clear the array
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```